# How to make a button to hide one column and expand another column?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web using wordpress and elementor page builder.

I intended to make a template that allows "distraction-free reading" on post. Mainly, the template has 2 columns: "post-sidebar" and "post-main". Clicking on a button will hide the "post-sidebar" and then align:center and widen the  "post-main" width.

I know nothing about code, but after researching in the past few days, I managed to hide the sidebar on click, but I still don't know how to handle the remaining column as intended.

I insert html widget as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Focus Reading</button>

<div id="focus-button">

</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("post-sidebar");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Would be great of anyone may take a look and have opnion on this.

Many thanks, sincerely,

Comment: There is no ``id`` **post-sidebar**, instead it should be **focus-button**

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery for ease of use

Give the button a class say class="focus-reading" give the columns some classes like class="column1" the other class="column2" then do the following:

then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.focus-reading').click(function(){
      $('.column1').toggle();
      $('.column2').toggleClass("width100");
   });
});
```

Or something like that? That should toggle those elements off/on and just add a class to the style sheet .width100{} and make it however wide you want the remaining column.